# SQL Error - has more columns than were specified in the column list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve results from the below query but keep getting this error message:

> Msg 8158, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   'a' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

My query:

```
select
    * 
from 
    (select 
         customer_key as customer_id, updated_by as [Help Desk] 
     from 
         permission) a (nolock)
where 
    [Help Desk] is not null
```

Comment: the (nolock) should be next to permission table

Comment: noted, thanks @ken white

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    * 
from 
    (select 
         customer_key as customer_id, updated_by as [Help Desk] 
     from 
         permission with (nolock)) as a
```

Comment: Why this answer have down votes? It actually help me resolve my problem. I think if using or not using the no lock is a decision of the developer when to use it. What is important is to be aware of what does and in what environment can be a good option with out breaking something or showing incorrect or not committed data.

Comment: Thanks @Juan for complaining on my behalf. I do not know why it is down voted either but it does not matter to me as long as the answer helps you (that's really what I care most)

Comment: It's because it doesn't explain anything and is just code alone.